# Does printing some values continuously lowers the performance in parallel processing

Tags: parallel-processing

I have heard that,continuous  `Input/Ouput`  operations reduces performance in parallel processing. I have been continuously printing the values so that i can check how many iterations are passed. Does it really affects the speed of the process?

Answer (score 1):

yes, and the more threads the more the impact... IF you have 10 threads generating 10,000 numbers at a time for 30 seconds worth of numbers. they all will generate and then wait for the I/O operation.  You are better off keeping a count on each aditional thread, and then displaying them at the end.  Display I/O isn't as bad as disk I/O, but the problem still exists.

ex: thread 1 did 30,000 passes, thread 2 did 36,000 passes, etc.